# Need a format mask to retain leading 0 in 0.3100 and to trim trailing zeros to create 0.31

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3, C#, ASP.NET 4.5 and Razor.

I need to convert any input decimals to 3 decimal places, but also with a leading 0. Also I need to trim any trailing zeros.

So I need:

1.4567 -> 1.458

1.4000 -> 1.4

Currently I am using the following:

```
Model.Value.ToString("#.###")
```

But I have discovered that this strips leading zeros ie:

0.71567 -> .716 not 0.716 which I need.

How do I ensure that the leading zero is retained, while meeting my other formatting requirements.

ie 0.71567 -> 0.716

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `Model.Value.ToString("0.###")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke. Thank you for this. I think I need to accept your answer since you were first in with the correct one.

Comment: Accept Donal's - Its correct (I don't need the points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Model.Value.ToString("0.###")
```

Seems to be what you're looking for.